# Why can't I run this portable exe from my USB drive? "Cannot access the specified device..."

Tags: windows-10, usb, data-recovery, recovery, portable-apps

I'm trying to use R-Undelete which has a portable installed on a 16GB PNY usb drive. When I try to start anything on the drive it returns this message :

[image: 1]

So I was trying to update the drivers for USB controllers and noticed it looks to me like too many drivers installed.
[image]

Any advice is appreciated

PS: I've tried changing permissions to the folders on the USB and I've noticed whenever I uncheck the read-only box in properties it always re-checks itself after I click apply and ok. Also - it has the AOMEI Partition Assistant bootable recovery drive installed.
[image: 3]

Comment: Are you sure that the disk is fully working ?

Comment: running with admin rights?